# Is this an overly complicated pthreads code?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

This is supposed to create two threads and have them announce their ID and the PID they assigned to. Some basic error checking is implemented as well.

Is there is a simpler way to do this without sacrificing error checking?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>


pthread_t tid[1];

void* doSomething(void *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    const char* a[2];
    a[0]="Client(1)";
    a[1]="Server(2)";


    while (i<2)
    {

        if ( pthread_equal(id,tid[i]) )
        printf("\n I'm the %s! My ID is: %ld. Our PID is= %d\n",a[i], (long int)&(tid[i]) , getpid());
        i++;


    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int error;

    while(i < 2)
    {
        error = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomething, NULL);
        if (error != 0){
            printf("\n Error creating thread %d:[%s]",i+1, strerror(error));
            }
    else{
        if(i==0){
            printf("\n Principal thread: Client thread (%i) created! Thread ID: %ld \n", i+1, (long int)&(tid[0]));
            }
        if(i==1){
            printf("\n Principal thread: Server thread (%i) created! Thread ID: %ldn", i+1, (long int)&(tid[1]));       
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
    if ( pthread_join((tid[0]), NULL) == 0){
    printf ("\n Client has closed \n");
    } else {    
    printf ("\n Client closed with an error \n");
    }
    if ( pthread_join((tid[1]), NULL) == 0){
    printf ("\n Server has closed  \n");
    }else{  
    printf ("\nClient closed with an error  \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not too complex; just invoking undefined behaviour.  You've got `if ( pthread_equal(id,tid[i]) )` which will access `tid[0]` (OK) and `tid[1]` (not OK) because you defined `pthread_t tid[1];` so you're accessing the array out of bounds; who knows what is happening.  Your code in `main()` should use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop with all the spare parts scattered around the code.  And it should not go accessing the `tid` array out of bounds either.

Comment: For codereview, please ask on [codereview.se], not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about code review which belongs to [codereview.se].

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @FUZxxl this is not a "valid" close reason. Close reasons should state why a question is off topic on the current site. What you should write in this close reason (instead of "belongs to ...") is whythe question is a bad fit for SO. Something like: "SO rules states that we help to solve specific problems, of which reviewing code is not one". Alternatively use the "too broad" close-reason

Comment: @Vogel612 I did state why its off-topic. This question asks for code review. Code review is not within the scope of this site. How could I have made this any clearer?

Comment: @FUZxxl You're fully correct, but the [help/on-topic] does not **explicitly** state Code Reviews are off-topic here. For OP to understand you will need to provide reasoning that can be led back to what's on that page. In this case usually "Too Broad", or "unclear".

Comment: or maybe even better, refer to the "specific programming problem" clause...

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the *undefined behaviour* mentioned in the comments, you can also rewrite the code to *not* use the `while` loop and simplify the thread function such as:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2];

void* doSomething(void *arg)
{
    char *str = arg;
    printf("\n I'm the %s! My ID is: %ld. Our PID is= %d\n", str, (long) pthread_self() , getpid());
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int error;
    const char *a[2] = {"Client (1)", "Client (2)" };

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        error = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomething, (void*)a[i]);
        if (error != 0)
            printf("\n Error creating thread %d:[%s]",i+1, strerror(error));
        else
            printf("\n Principal thread: Client thread (%i) created! Thread ID: %ld \n", i+1, (long int)&(tid[i]));
    }

    if ( pthread_join((tid[0]), NULL) == 0){
    printf ("\n Client has closed \n");
    } else {
    printf ("\n Client closed with an error \n");
    }
    if ( pthread_join((tid[1]), NULL) == 0){
    printf ("\n Server has closed  \n");
    }else{
    printf ("\nClient closed with an error  \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also skip the error checking on `pthread_join()`. There's not much you can do if it fails anyway.

Also, note casting `pthread_t` to `long` is not guaranteed to work. There's no standard format specifier to print it portably. If you are really concerned about it, convert it to `unsinged char*` and print the bytes.